# redirect_uri_mismatch when redirecting to Azure B2C

Tags: azure-ad-b2c

I've developed a web app that uses Azure B2C authentication based on the sample code you can download. It all works when I am developing / debugging but I get a `redirect_uri_mismatch` error when I click on the 'Sign In' button after I have deployed the app to Azure App Services and I updated the Redirect URL in the B2C application, any idea why? It does not even load the Azure UI

Documentation on the topic is VERY thin, probably because it is still in preview...

Comment: did you resolve the issue?

Answer (score 0):

You can use CallbackPath to set the correct route when authentication is successful

**Example:
options.CallbackPath = new PathString("/account/ExternalLogin");**

Comment: Here is the working copy of Azure b2c poc with dnx core

https://github.com/ayydevara/azure-b2c-poc.git

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem, I forgot to update the web.config file when I deploy the code. You need to set the web.config correctly according to the redirect url